# xmlrpc and System.Net.WebException .net 3.5 c#

Tags: c#, webrequest, xml-rpc

I use CookComputing.XmlRpc;

Trying to connect to trac using some requests but I get this:

> System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ReceiveFailure
>
> {"The underlying connection was
>   closed: An unexpected error occurred
>   on a receive."}
>
> {"Unable to read data
>   from the transport connection: An
>   existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host."}

A- when I run my application using Visual Studio 2008, the error is **intermittent**.

B- when I run my compiled application it **never works**.

C- when I use fiddler to listen, my application **always works** (from visual studio or compiled)

This is what I use:

```
//Trac Code
        [XmlRpcUrl("http://trac:8080/Project/login/xmlrpc")]
        public interface Trac : IXmlRpcProxy
        {
            [XmlRpcMethod("ticket.query")
            int[] query(string queryStr);

            [XmlRpcMethod("ticket.get")]
            object[] get(int id);
        }
```

Usage:

```
//sometimes it fails here:
int[] a = proxy.query("status!=closed&owner=" + user);
//sometimes here:
           foreach (int ticketid in a)
            {
                tickets.Add((proxy.get(ticketid))[3]);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
```

Comment: Can you get a wireshark trace of the error with the standalone application?

Answer (score 0):

the ´fiddler works´ remark reminds me off the ´buffered´ versus ´unbuffered´ streams. Since fiddler buffers the entire stream to show and then sends it on completely it might cause changes in behavior, visual studio debugger idem.

Not a real answer, but maybe a lead leading to one.